# When the conection to the Oracle DB is dropped, PooledConnection has already been closed is printed continuously

Tags: wso2-esb

I've installed wso2esb-4.9.0 and the master datasource is configured to a oracle DB. When the connection to the Oracle Database is dropped due to a network connectivity issue the following error is continually printed even though the connection is back again. Only after a restart the exception stops.

TID: [-1234] [] [2016-05-16 00:53:21,457] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.utils.RegistryUtils} -  Failed to construct the connectionId. {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.utils.RegistryUtils}
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.getMetaData(PhysicalConnection.java:3131)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor28.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms.ConnectionRollbackOnReturnInterceptor.invoke(ConnectionRollbackOnReturnInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:71)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState.invoke(ConnectionState.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.TrapException.invoke(TrapException.java:41)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:80)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.getMetaData(Unknown Source)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.utils.RegistryUtils.getConnectionId(RegistryUtils.java:194)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCDatabaseTransaction$ManagedRegistryConnection.getConnectionId(JDBCDatabaseTransaction.java:1133)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCDatabaseTransaction$ManagedRegistryConnection.rollback(JDBCDatabaseTransaction.java:1288)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCTransactionManager.rollbackTransaction(JDBCTransactionManager.java:120)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCLogsDAO.rollbackTransaction(JDBCLogsDAO.java:335)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCLogsDAO.getLogList(JDBCLogsDAO.java:306)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.getLogs(EmbeddedRegistry.java:2332)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.getLogs(CacheBackedRegistry.java:402)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.getLogsInternal(UserRegistry.java:1806)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$3600(UserRegistry.java:60)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$37.run(UserRegistry.java:1777)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$37.run(UserRegistry.java:1774)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.getLogs(UserRegistry.java:1774)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.ResourceSubmitter.submitResource(ResourceSubmitter.java:119)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.ResourceSubmitter.run(ResourceSubmitter.java:76)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

master-datasources.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><datasources-configuration xmlns:svns="http://org.wso2.securevault/configuration">

<providers>
    <provider>org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms.RDBMSDataSourceReader</provider>
</providers>

<datasources>

    <datasource>
        <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
        <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
        <jndiConfig>
            <name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</name>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.xx.x.xxx:1528/dvdb</url>
        <username>esbuser</username>
                <password svns:secretAlias="Datasources.WSO2_CARBON_DB.Configuration.Password">password</password>
                <driverClassName>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>80</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                <minIdle>5</minIdle>
                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1 FROM DUAL</validationQuery>
                <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>
<datasource>
        <name>WSO2_REG_DB</name>
        <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
        <jndiConfig>
            <name>jdbc/WSO2REG</name>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.xx.x.xxx:1528/dvdb</url>
                <username>reguser</username>
                <password svns:secretAlias="Datasources.WSO2_REG_DB.Configuration.Password">password</password>
                <driverClassName>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                <minIdle>5</minIdle>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1 FROM DUAL</validationQuery>
                <testWhileIdle>true</testWhileIdle>
        <timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis>1800000</timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis>
        <numTestsPerEvictionRun>5</numTestsPerEvictionRun>
        <minEvictableIdleTimeMillis>3600000</minEvictableIdleTimeMillis>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>
    <!-- For an explanation of the properties, see: http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html -->
    <!--datasource>
        <name>SAMPLE_DATA_SOURCE</name>
        <jndiConfig>
            <name></name>
            <environment>
                <property name="java.naming.factory.initial"></property>
                <property name="java.naming.provider.url"></property>
            </environment>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>

                <defaultAutoCommit></defaultAutoCommit>
                <defaultReadOnly></defaultReadOnly>
                <defaultTransactionIsolation>NONE|READ_COMMITTED|READ_UNCOMMITTED|REPEATABLE_READ|SERIALIZABLE</defaultTransactionIsolation>
                <defaultCatalog></defaultCatalog>
                <username></username>
                <password svns:secretAlias="WSO2.DB.Password"></password>
                <maxActive></maxActive>
                <maxIdle></maxIdle>
                <initialSize></initialSize>
                <maxWait></maxWait>

                <dataSourceClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</dataSourceClassName>
                <dataSourceProps>
                    <property name="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Test1</property>
                    <property name="user">root</property>
                    <property name="password">123</property>
                </dataSourceProps>

            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource-->

</datasources>
```

repository/conf/registry.xml

```
<currentDBConfig>wso2registry</currentDBConfig>
<readOnly>false</readOnly>
<enableCache>true</enableCache>
<registryRoot>/</registryRoot>

<dbConfig name="wso2registry">
    <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</dataSource>
</dbConfig>

<dbConfig name="remoteRegistry">
    <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2REG</dataSource>
</dbConfig>

<remoteInstance url="https://registryhost:9453/registry">
    <id>9453</id>
    <dbConfig>remoteRegistry</dbConfig>
    <readOnly>false</readOnly>
    <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
</remoteInstance>

<mount path="/_system/config" overwrite="false">
    <instanceId>9453</instanceId>
    <targetPath>/_system/nodes</targetPath>
</mount>

<mount path="/_system/governance" overwrite="false">
    <instanceId>9453</instanceId>
    <targetPath>/_system/governance</targetPath>
</mount>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was caused by a wrong line deleted at file repository/config/registry.xml.

I'd removed this code:

```
<dbConfig name="wso2registry">
    <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</dataSource>
</dbConfig>
```

Instead of add another dbConfig tag.

For me, the correction was re-add that tag. Like this:

```
<wso2registry>

<!-- These are used to define the DB configuration and the basic parameters to be used for the registry -->

<currentDBConfig>wso2registry</currentDBConfig>
<readOnly>false</readOnly>
<enableCache>true</enableCache>
<registryRoot>/</registryRoot>

<!-- This defines the default database and its configuration of the registry -->

<dbConfig name="wso2registry">
    <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</dataSource>
</dbConfig>

<dbConfig name="sharedregistry">
    <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2RegistryDB</dataSource>
</dbConfig>
...
...
</wso2registry>
```

Hope this post help you...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

In the master-datasources.xml
1- set the datasource name same as the jndiConfig name
2- set 2 differents datasources with different names for both registry and user management.
Here my master-datasources.xml

```
<datasource>
        <name>WSO2REG_DB</name>
        <description>The datasource used for registry</description>
        <jndiConfig>
            <name>jdbc/WSO2REG_DB</name>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/registry?autoReconnect=true&amp;relaxAutoCommit=true&amp;</url>
                <username>apiuser</username>
                <password>apimanager</password>
                <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>

    <datasource>
        <name>WSO2UM_DB</name>
        <description>The datasource used for user management</description>
        <jndiConfig>
            <name>jdbc/WSO2UM_DB</name>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userstore?autoReconnect=true&amp;relaxAutoCommit=true&amp;
                </url>
                <username>apiuser</username>
                <password>apimanager</password>
                <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>
```

In the registry.xml
1- set the wso2registry dbConfig with the user management data source
2- set the govregistry dbConfig with the registry data source

Here my registry.xml

```
<dbConfig name="wso2registry">
    <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2UM_DB</dataSource>
</dbConfig>

<dbConfig name="govregistry">
    <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2REG_DB</dataSource>
</dbConfig>
```

It worked for me and my IS-Server could start properly. Hope it will work for you too, when the problem isn't already fixed.